# proxy_cache_bypass keeps serving old cached response if URL changes to non-cacheable

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Under normal circumstances, when using `proxy_cache_bypass` nginx will fetch a fresh copy from upstream, and overwrite the cached response with the new one.

But if the URL changes from a cacheable to a non-cacheable response (for example to a 4xx response with `Cache-Control: no-cache`), then using `proxy_cache_bypass` will indeed serve a fresh copy from upstream, but it will leave the old copy in the cache.

Which means that everytime the URL is requested without triggering `proxy_cache_bypass`, it will keep serving the old cache.

I guess this is an intended behaviour, because `proxy_cache_bypass` only *overwrites* cached responses by saving a new one, and a `no-cache` response means there is nothing to save? Is this what's happening?

How can I solve this? I don't want to enable caching for 4xx responses...

I'm running nginx/1.14.2

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:70m max_size=28g inactive=1d;
proxy_temp_path /var/cache/nginx/tmp;
proxy_cache my-cache;
proxy_cache_key $remote_user$scheme$host$request_uri;

proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_429;

proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;

proxy_read_timeout 90;
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

etag off;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell nginx to cache only 200, 301 and 302 responses by specifying

```
proxy_cache_valid 10m;
```

This tells nginx to cache valid responses for ten minutes.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use higher caching times. Right now I'm setting it at 24h.
Besides, I think `Cache-Control` overrides `proxy_cache_valid`

Comment: You can specify any time with `proxy_cache_valid`. The main point of this directive is that it limits caching to only these response statuses. Other status codes are not cached.

Comment: I did that and it didn't change anything.
The problem is not that it's caching unwanted status codes, but that responses that change from a cacheable to a non cacheable `Cache-Control`, keep serving the cached response.

Comment: This does not solve OP's problem. In fact it in almost completely irrelevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. That's why they want you to use the paid version to get the [proxy_cache_purge](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_purge) directive